# Applet User-agent

Tags: applet, user-agent

This is a simple question, but I didn´t found any documentation about this. When an applet makes a request, how is the user agent of the request. I want to know the applet user-agent expression to detect if a request comes from an applet.

I make two test, with IE7 and Firefox 3.0.5 with JDK 1.6.0_03 and the user agent was "Mozilla/4.0 (Windows 2003 5.2) Java/1.6.0_03" in both, but I can´t generalize from two test.

Thanks in advance,
   Jonathan.

Answer (score 1):

Better later than never.

The browsers IE, Safari, Firefox and Chrome lets the Java applet's request with user agent header "Mozilla/4.0 (`operative system info` ) Java/1.6.0_03" . Opera puts its own header instead of the applet header.

Hope this helps somebody.